# How to retain only highest frequency rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server

[image: Menu Items]

I am trying to retain only the highest frequency rows.

Eg:

```
Latte      | 4.2 | 1015
Flat White | 4.2 | 423
Cappuccino | 4.2 | 329
```

This is the query I used to get the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   "TBL_ITEM"."ItemModName1",
   ("TBL_ITEM"."ItemPrice" / "TBL_ITEM"."Qty") as PricePerUnit,
   Count (*) as Frequency
FROM 
    "dbo"."tbl_item" AS "TBL_ITEM"

WHERE (
   "TBL_ITEM"."ItemPrice" > 0.0
   AND "TBL_ITEM"."UnitPrice" > 0.0
   AND "TBL_ITEM"."Type" = 1
   AND "TBL_ITEM"."CheckDate" BETWEEN '20200421 00:00:00.000' AND '20200427 23:59:59.997'
)
GROUP BY 
   "TBL_ITEM"."ItemModName1",
   ("TBL_ITEM"."ItemPrice" / "TBL_ITEM"."Qty")
ORDER BY   Count (*) DESC
```

Comment: If you will share sample data in the text instead of an image that will be helpful to answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT ItemModName1, PricePerUnit, Frequency
FROM (
  SELECT 
    "TBL_ITEM"."ItemModName1",
    ("TBL_ITEM"."ItemPrice" / "TBL_ITEM"."Qty") as PricePerUnit,
    COUNT(*) as Frequency,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "TBL_ITEM"."ItemModName1" ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as rn
  FROM "dbo"."tbl_item" AS "TBL_ITEM"
  WHERE (
    "TBL_ITEM"."ItemPrice" > 0.0
    AND "TBL_ITEM"."UnitPrice" > 0.0
    AND "TBL_ITEM"."Type" = 1
    AND "TBL_ITEM"."CheckDate" BETWEEN '20200421 00:00:00.000' AND '20200427 23:59:59.997'
  )
  GROUP BY 
    "TBL_ITEM"."ItemModName1",
    ("TBL_ITEM"."ItemPrice" / "TBL_ITEM"."Qty")
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Frequency DESC
```

You don't need `DISTINCT` because you use GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks Forpas. I'm still getting the same results. I'm looking forward to get distinct itemmodname1 based on highest frequency. Appreciate your help